# Move between layouts in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'm developing an app in Xamarin Android. I want to use a button and then move to the next layout (I have 3 layouts). I'm able to move from layout1 to layout2 but not from layout 2 to layout 3.

LayoutOne

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#1f1e1e"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:text="One"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#484848"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

//////////////////////////////////

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutOne);

        Button btnOne = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnOne);
        btnOne.Click += btnOne_Click;
    }
private void btnOne_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutTwo);
    }
```

LayoutTwo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#1f1e1e"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:text="Two"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#484848"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

//////////////////////////////////

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutTwo);

        Button btnTwo = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnTwo);
        btnTwo.Click += btnTwo_Click;
    }
private void btnTwo_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutThree);
    }
```

LayoutThree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#1f1e1e"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is Layout3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

There is no errors and the app runs. I run it through my phone using usb debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to navigate between three different layouts,a common method is to create three different activities and set the three layouts for them.
For example, `FirstActivity` loads `LayoutOne` ,`SecondActivity` loads `LayoutTwo` and `ThirdActivity` loads `LayoutThree` , after that we can use `Intent` to navigate between them.

Please refer to the following code:

**FirstActivity.cs**

```
public class FirstActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutOne);

        Button btnOne = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnOne);
        btnOne.Click += BtnOne_Click;
    }

    private void BtnOne_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutTwo);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,typeof(SecondActivity));

        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.cs**

```
public class SecondActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutTwo);

        Button btnTwo = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnTwo);
        btnTwo.Click += btnTwo_Click;


    }

    private void btnTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutThree);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,typeof(ThirdActivity));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**ThirdActivity.cs**

```
public class ThirdActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here

       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LayoutThree);
    }
}
```